Matrix function of a measurable map $f$ is again measurable?
Consider a measurable map $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $. Define the matrix function as the induced map
\begin{equation}
 f: H^n \to H^n \\
A = \sum_i \lambda_i e_i e_i^T  \mapsto \sum_i f(\lambda_i) e_i e_i^T
\end{equation}
where $H^n = \{ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} | A^T = A \}  $ (thus the matrix function is well defined by the spectral theorem for symmetric matrices). Is the matrix function $f$ measurable, where the sigma algebra is the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n} $ ? Thanks
I am asking this in the context of random matrix theory so I want to know, if $X$ is a random matrix $f(X)$ is again a random matrix for $f$ measurable. But so far I have only found, that the $i$-th Eigenvalue maps $\lambda_i(A)$ are measurable.

Yes, this is indeed the case. The easiest way to see this is to use the fact that the Borel algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$ coincides with the product of the Borel algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ with itself $n$ times (in the sense of product measures). This is a small exercise, which by induction on $n$ essentially reduces to the case $n = 2$. From this, you argue that your map is measurable because all the component maps are measurable.

How does one see that the component maps are measurable ? Calling the standard basis $|n>$ the (n,m) component is going to be $\sum_i f(\lambda_i) <n,e_i><e_i,m> $ but I don't see how this is measurable, because the eigenvectors are not that simple to analyse ?
